# How to get the next ContentItem Id for a custom form in orchard?

Tags: forms, razor, orchardcms

I'm porting an existing website to Orchard. The site is quite complex: imagine a layout with two zones: body and aside

when the content is of ContentType "Service" the Content-Service.cshtml alternate view that render this shape also inject another shape in the aside zone using

WorkContext.Layout.Aside.Add(New.Parts_PdfDocument(Model.ContentItem.Service.PdfDocument),"1.1");

that works great and in the aside zone it is displayed the alternate Parts.PdfDocument.cshtml

from which I can access to all the content i'm interested in (the info about the PDF)

anyway it is required that in order to download the PDF the user fills a form ContactRequest (FirstName, LastName...) The form will then start a workflow that will alert win an email some specific user (that's done and already works)

My first idea was to programmatically create a ContentItem for the ContactRequest by simulating what happens in the Orchard.CustomForms Module's CustomFormPartDriver.
In the Parts.CaseStudies.cshtml i've wrote

```
@{
        var services = WorkContext.Resolve<IOrchardServices>();

        var contentManager = services.ContentManager;
        var contact = contentManager.New("ContactRequest");
        var editor = contentManager.BuildEditor(contact);

}
```

so to obtain a valid id and then use it as follow

```
@using(Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost(Url.Action("Create", "Item", new { area = "Orchard.CustomForms", id = editor.ContentItem.Id}))){ /*[...] form fields here */ }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seems to work, and the Id is always zero.
i've also tryed to add

```
contentManager.Create(contact);
```

And this time i obtain an Id different from zero, but it get incremented each time i visit the page, independently from the fact that i send or not the form, which is different from the normal orchard form module behaviour that propsoed the same id until the form is sent and saved.

**Question:**
Which is the correct way to instantiate a form editor so to get the correct Id to pass to the Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost method?

is there a better way other the one i'm trying to achieve? i would like to avoid to write modules, if possible

Comment: I was wrong in my interpretation of how orchard works, it tourns out that the id passed in the url is not increasing even uppon save but it is the id of the widgwt that holds the form, i've then just to discover how to retrieve such id, at worst i'll hard code it as i know it

Comment: Hacking the forms module seems very complicated, whereas a simple module with a simple controller would get the job done easily.